# 1с разделитель каталогов

Tags: linux, 1с

Есть у СБИС внешняя обработка для 1с. Там много работы с xml файлами и пути к файлам захардкожены через `\` ну а у меня линукс. Через найти и заменить поправил пути, но хотелось бы исправления отправить разработчику и вопрос вот в чем. Есть ли константа в 1с для разделения каталогов? Есть ли функция для сборки полного пути из частей? Аналоги питоновского os.path.join и os.sep

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Есть глобальные методы:

клиент/сервер:
ПолучитьРазделительПути()
ПолучитьРазделительПутиКлиента()

только сервер:
ПолучитьРазделительПутиСервера()

Для сборки пути можно использовать массив строк и функцию СтрСоединить, например:
СтрСоединить(МассивСтрок, ПолучитьРазделительПути())

Comment: Остается разобраться где клиент там где сервер. В самом начале выбор пути на клиенте, а вызовы на сервере...